# how to save Sklearn lda model output to csv?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

How to save Sklearn LDA  model output to csv ?
it does not have show_topics command as genism lDA model.

```
def selected_topics(model, vectorizer, top_n=10):
for idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
    print("Topic %d:" % (idx))
    print([(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[i], topic[i])
                    for i in topic.argsort()[:-top_n - 1:-1]])
```

This is good for print but how to save these results to csv?

Answer (score 0):

```
def selected_topics(model, vectorizer, top_n=10):
    results={}
    for idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        topicId='Topic'+str(idx)
        print("Topic %d:" % (idx))
        topic_name = " ".join([(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[i]
                    for i in topic.argsort()[:-top_n - 1:-1]])
        results[topicId]=topic_name
    return results
```

you can Write the results to a Json and then CSV file

## To Json

```
import json,csv
results = selected_topics(model, vectorizer, top_n=10)
res_file = open(outputFile,'w')
res_file.write(json.dumps(results))
res_file.close()
```

## Json to csv

```
input = open(res_file)
data = json.load(input)
input.close()

output = csv.writer("output_csv.csv")

output.writerow(data[0].keys())  # header row

for item in data:
    output.writerow(item.values())
```

Let me know if this doesn't help you

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-81b261fec713> in <module>()
----> 1 selected_topics(lda, vectorizer)

<ipython-input-151-3cb9210a877d> in selected_topics(model, vectorizer, top_n)
      6         print("Topic %d:" % (idx))
      7         topic_name = " ".join([(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[i], topic[i])
----> 8                                for i in topic.argsort()[:-top_n - 1:-1]])
      9 
     10 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found.Its throw me an error.

Comment: is it a possible way to generate csv by creating a loop as we create in genism ?.

Comment: yes you can create, replace   " ".join([(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[i], topic[i]) to " ".join([(vectorizer.get_feature_names()[i]

Comment: What is the purpose of writing to json first?

Comment: 20     input.close()
     21 
---> 22     output = csv.writer("output_csv.csv")
     23 
     24     output.writerow(data[0].keys())  # header row

TypeError: argument 1 must have a "write" method

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own .Running the loop works for me .

```
 def show_topics(vectorizer=vectorizer, lda_model=lda, n_words=20):
    keywords = np.array(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
    topic_keywords = []
    for topic_weights in lda_model.components_:
        top_keyword_locs = (-topic_weights).argsort()[:n_words]
        topic_keywords.append(keywords.take(top_keyword_locs))
    return topic_keywords

topic_keywords = show_topics(vectorizer=vectorizer, lda_model=lda, n_words=15)        

# Topic - Keywords Dataframe
df_topic_keywords = pd.DataFrame(topic_keywords)
df_topic_keywords.columns = ['Word '+str(i) for i in range(df_topic_keywords.shape[1])]
df_topic_keywords.index = ['Topic '+str(i) for i in range(df_topic_keywords.shape[0])]
df_topic_keywords
```

Answer (score -1):

You can export the results by first creating a pandas dataframe and saving the LDA model results to that dataframe(through a loop). Later on exporting it to a csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
pd.DataFrame(savedresults).to_csv("all_model_ouput.csv")
```